# pthread_kill returns error number 11

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, signals, posix

I have a thread currently stopped by pselect

```
(void)pselect(1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &select_mask);
```

the sigmask is initialized this way.

```
(void)sigfillset(&select_mask);
(void)sigdelset(&select_mask, 37);
```

debug in gdb

```
4 Thread 0x7ffff7fce710 (LWP 28287)  0x00007ffff6a24dab in pselect () from ./libc.so.6
```

When i try to to send signal number 37 to this thread to get it out from pselect.
It returns 11.

```
(gdb) call pthread_kill(0x7ffff7fce710,37)
$26 = 11
```

trying other signals will return 0,because other signals are supposed to be blocked.

```
(gdb) call pthread_kill(0x7ffff7fce710,3)
$27 = 0
```

what is 11 means here? EAGAIN? 
And how to get rid of it and end that pselect?

I'm using 64bit suselinux 11 system.

Comment: have you googled for something like possix or pthreads error codes? i would bet that there is something to find in tehir docs

Comment: @Zaibis I've done that but find no clue. Posix offical man page only provide 2 error descriptions ,ESRCH and EINVAL. Both are not my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EAGAIN is an undocumented Linux return code for `pthread_kill()` (implemented in terms of [`tgkill()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/tgkill) on Linux) meaning that [the receiving real-time signal queue has overflowed](https://lkml.org/lkml/2009/3/18/61).

My guess is that you've masked off the signal and sent thousands of it before the call to `pselect()`.  On my system I observe this behavior compiling with `-pthread` and sending just over 15202 instances of a real-time signal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I haven't found a solution yet.I restart my system and the problem get fixed.I failed to find the real reason for this.If real-time signal queue has overflowed how to clean it up or if there is a recover mechanism?

Comment: @oyss, my guess is you are accidentally signaling the wrong thread instead of the pselect()ing thread.  (Your substitution of `raise()`, for example, would signal the calling thread.)

Answer (score 2):

Catch the return value of pthread_kill and run it through the `strerror` function. You'll get a string returned with the error specified.

```
if ((error = pthread_kill(...)) != 0)
    printf("pthread_kill error: %s\n", strerror(error));
```

Also, while trying to simulate what you're doing, i ran into a similar issue. My solution was to simply use `info threads` and `raise`, like so

```
(gdb) info threads
  2 thread 1024621  thread () at main.c:7
* 1 thread 1025084  0x0fda2445 in _thread_sys___thrsleep () from /usr/lib/libc.so.65.0
(gdb) call raise(1, 37)
$1 = 0
(gdb) detach
```

Comment: raise is equivalent to pthread_kill(pthread_self(), sig); and takes only one arguments. I tried raise and returned the same errno 11.